# Pulling information from Instagram api using JQuery

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp, instagram

So lately I've been trying out making requests to the Instagram API via ajax and using jquery. I seem to be having a little trouble though. I am trying to pull information available from the JSON array that comes via the GET request and can only seem to access a small part of the array and everything else comes in as either undefined or blank. Here is the code i'm using:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "jsonp",
cache: false,
url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/olympics/media/recent?client_id={clientid}",
success: function(response) {
  for (var i=0; i<25; i++)  
  {
    $("#photos").html(response.data[i].comments.from.username);
  }

  }
});
```

Just using the {clientid} to represent where that would go and the test information is supposedly coming from data[i].comments.from.username however this is not working and I'm drawing blank. I have used JSFiddle to try and figure out where I'm going wrong but with no success.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get past this hurdle? I've not had any issues with any of the other API's i've used only this one. Any code that may help would be good too!

Thanks!

Comment: What response do you get? Can you post the json that comes back?

Comment: Nothing seems to be coming back at all, I'm confused as to why this is and putting the &callback=? on the end didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm using `getJSON()` instead of `ajax()` to grab my data, heres an example of how I'm doing it.  http://jsfiddle.net/wPheR/3 . Unfortunately it seems jsfiddle is on instagrams block list, but at least you can see the code.

Comment: Cool, ok that kinda worked except I'm getting only one coming back i.e. I decided to try from.profile_picture and only got one picture come back, is there something in my For loop that isn't right? Also should I add the &callback=? on the end again or won't that make a different? I never had this trouble with Facebook or Twitter APIs

Comment: comments.data.from.profile_picture, will also require it's own loop, as one image could have multiple comments. ie comments.data[i].from.profile_picture. 

Best bet is to do a `console.log(data)`, and you can see the structure of the JSON returned.

Comment: ok the $.each() isn't working at all and JQuery doesn't seem to recognise the getJSON() function which could possibly say why its not working.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/olympics/media/recent?client_id=c8ed6cc57c6c474a9661c26c318daf61", 
    function(json) {
        $.each(json.data, function(i, item){
            $("#photos").html("<img src='" + item.images.low_resolution.url + "' />");
        });
    });
});

Comment: your testing this in a hosted environment and not from a file right? because unless your site is being loaded from http:// your not going to get any results from the cross domain request.

Comment: Yeah was just coming back onto here to apologise and say my bad I was doing it from a static file on my HD not from my site, sorry. Thank you for the help though as it came back working fine!

Comment: Yeah if you write up an answer i shall accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was sound, but the problem is that your viewing the page from your computers file system `file://....../index.html` which will not work for cross domain requests.

You must run your code from a hosted environment `http://localhost/..../index.html` since ajax makes http requests, and these requests must go to the same domain/server.

You will probably also have to set the 'WEBSITE URL' in your instagram app (on instagrams website), which the instagram API will use to authenticate your requests against your `client_id` to ensure they are coming from the correct domain. Simply put, you will have to host your files on the same domain you specify in your app on the instagram website, or the requests will fail.

**UPDATE** 
Actually that last bit doesn't seem to be true, while some API's require you to host the files on the same domain specified within the app, instagram does not.

Just make sure your running your scripts from a hosted environment.

Comment: Thank you for the help it was much appreciated. I have implemented on my web hosting site and it works perfectly. You were definitely correct about it having to be on the same server though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Try appending `&callback=?` to the url.

```
url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/olympics/media/recent?client_id={clientid}&callback=?",
```